# A functional inequality over integers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given positive integers $N$ and $n$, we define a function $f(x)$ as follows:

$$f(x):=\frac{x^2-3x}{2}~\text{ when } x\leq N,$$

and

$$f(x):=\frac{1}{2n}x^2+\frac{n-4}{2}x~\text{ when } x>N.$$

Question: Does there exist an positive integer $M$, such that for any integer $x_0>M$ and partition $\sum_{i=1}^s x_i=x_0$ (here $s\geq 1$ and $x_i$ is a positive integer for each $1\leq i\leq s$), we have

$$f(x_0)\geq \sum^s_{i=1} f(x_i).$$

Comment: what is $n$ in the derfinition where $x>N$?

Comment: @DS The $N$ is a fixed positive integer (which one does not know its actual value).

Comment: I'm asking about small n

Comment: @DS Sorry, here $n$ is also a fixed positive integer whose value is not known.

Comment: Try this for small values of $n$, see what happens